# why loss function is giving output as nan and how to resolve this issue in Artificial neural network model. I am passing just 3 features in it

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

Here is the image for the values of the data i am feeding in to the neural network:

[image: the values of the data i am feeding in to the neural network]

As you can see that this is dl ann problem and i am try to use it for classification i have created two hidden layers with 2 neuron in each of them.

```py
        import keras
    
        # initialsing the ann
        from keras.models import Sequential
    # to add different layers to ANN
        from keras.layers import Dense
        classifier=Sequential()
        classifier.add(Dense(units = 2, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', 
        activation = tf.keras.activations.tanh, input_dim = 8))
        classifier.add(Dense(units = 2, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', 
        activation = tf.keras.activations.tanh))
        classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
```

Here is the image for that nan output:

[image: here is the image for that nan output]

Answer (score 0):

After defining your model, and before training, you must compile your model. Your compile phase is about defining loss, optimizer and metrics for the model to be evaluated on.

Comment: ya i have compiled it ,i founded the error ,the ann behave strangely when our train data has nan values in it. when i removed all nan values it performed well.

Comment: but still i wonder why loss function become nan due to few missing values in our data.

Comment: In response to your first comment, that is a good notice to remember. I will keep that in mind. @VanditTyagi